# Xpath not working Google Chrome for Xml Document Scrapy Python

Tags: html, python-2.7, google-chrome, xpath, scrapy

Xpath is not working in Google Chrome.

$x('//url')

returns = [] # Empty

$x('//div[@id="webkit-xml-viewer-source-xml"]')

returns = [] #Empty

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="webkit-xml-viewer-source-xml">
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <url>
      <loc>https://www.sample.co.uk/</loc>
      <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
   </url>

   <url>
       <loc>https://www.sample1.co.uk/motherboardbundles/</loc>
       <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
   </url>

   <url>
      <loc>https://www.sample2.co.uk/barebonebundles/</loc>
      <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
   </url>   
 </urlset></div>
```

Please tell me whats wrong with my xpath.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Syyed

Please see the below image of actual Html  .
[image]

For xpath Please see below.

[image]
You can see that i am getting NULL (Empty) when i use Xpath in developer tool(google chrome).

Comment: You'll have to tell us a bit more on how you are running XPath over your document (ie. show some code)

Comment: `//url` means `url` with no namespace, but you seem to use a namespace. You need to specify it in the XPath expression, too.

Comment: You can read about Scrapy selectors and XML namespaces [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#removing-namespaces) and [here](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#ad-hoc-namespaces-references).

Comment: Thanks @Paul please let me try your links.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Paul by using headers in request i got my result.

import requests
from parsel import Selector
text = requests.get('https://www.sample.co.uk/sitemap.xml',  headers={'User-Agent':'my user agent '}).text